# GLib-GObject-WARNING: GtkToplevelAccessible in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gtk

I am trying to run voyant-tool in Ubuntu 18.04 with openjdk version "1.8.0_242" and getting following error: GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 12:59:29.522: invalid cast from 'GtkToplevelAccessible' to 'JawToplevel'. The GUI is opening but not allowing to select any option. The same is running happily in Ubuntu 16,04 with the same Java version. Tried a couple of quick fix after Googling it but not able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: upgrade to openjdk-11 by this command in terminal:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk
```

I also, on 18.04, got the same warning while using javax.swing on openjdk 8 version "1.8.0_242" but if I upgraded to the latest openjdk11 (currently version "11.0.6") then I got no warning with the same source code. So it seems to be a bug related to the javax.swing implementation in openjdk8.

If you need to stay on Java 8 I have not found any solution but to stay on 16.04...